# Get nothing when read url to string

Tags: java, android, url

I try to read a json string from a url:

```
String message = "http://cs-server.usc.edu:12695/examples/servlet/Moviefb?title=batman&title_type=feature";

    URL website;
    String str1 = "";

    try {
        website = new URL(message);
        URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            str1 += inputLine;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "catch1", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "catch2", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And then I use `Toast`to show what's in `str1`

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                str1, 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But I get nothing. And I got an exception,it shows `catch2`. These code are in my Android Application Project in Eclipse.

When I copy and past these code to my ordinary Java Project, it works.

the new stacktrace:

```
        12-13 09:02:28.909: W/System.err(1015): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
12-13 09:02:28.949: W/System.err(1015):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
12-13 09:02:29.079: W/Trace(1015): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-13 09:02:29.149: W/System.err(1015):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-13 09:02:29.159: W/System.err(1015):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-13 09:02:29.179: W/Trace(1015): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-13 09:02:29.219: W/Trace(1015): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-13 09:02:29.239: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
12-13 09:02:29.328: W/Trace(1015): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-13 09:02:29.428: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
12-13 09:02:29.549: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
12-13 09:02:29.609: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
12-13 09:02:29.669: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
12-13 09:02:29.669: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
12-13 09:02:29.719: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
12-13 09:02:29.819: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
12-13 09:02:29.879: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
12-13 09:02:29.959: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
12-13 09:02:29.959: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
12-13 09:02:29.959: W/System.err(1015):     at com.example.hwnine.Show$1.doInBackground(Show.java:48)
12-13 09:02:30.229: W/System.err(1015):     at com.example.hwnine.Show$1.doInBackground(Show.java:1)
12-13 09:02:30.268: W/System.err(1015):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-13 09:02:30.268: W/System.err(1015):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-13 09:02:30.308: W/Trace(1015): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-13 09:02:30.308: W/Trace(1015): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-13 09:02:30.348: W/Trace(1015): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-13 09:02:30.368: W/System.err(1015):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-13 09:02:30.398: W/Trace(1015): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-13 09:02:30.479: W/System.err(1015):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-13 09:02:30.489: W/System.err(1015):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-13 09:02:30.499: W/System.err(1015):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-13 09:02:30.499: W/System.err(1015): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
12-13 09:02:30.519: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
12-13 09:02:30.519: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:59)
12-13 09:02:30.529: W/System.err(1015):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
12-13 09:02:30.539: W/System.err(1015):     ... 21 more
12-13 09:02:30.539: W/System.err(1015): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
12-13 09:02:30.559: W/System.err(1015):     ... 24 more
12-13 09:02:30.589: W/Trace(1015): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: For what platform are you building this?

Comment: I build this on Eclipse, ADT

Comment: Show your stacktrace as well.

Comment: any chance you are running this code on ui thread? newer sdk does not allow that

Comment: There are thousands lines of stacktrace in LogCat..

Comment: show the firsts lines else we cant help you. I refeer for what Android platform. Not is the same build for 2.3 or 4.0. If you are building for 2.2 use HttpClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this code on Android 3.0+ you will probably get [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html), since it looks like you do this on the main thread. You need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this types of tasks.

What you can do is:

```
final String message = "http://cs-server.usc.edu:12695/examples/servlet/Moviefb?title=batman&title_type=feature";

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    private String mErrDesc = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... paramArrayOfParams) {
       URL website;
       String str1 = null;

       try {
           website = new URL(message);
           URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();

           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

           String inputLine;
           while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
               str1 += inputLine;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            mErrDesc = "MalformedURLException thrown";
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mErrDesc = "Exception thrown";
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return str1;
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
        if (str != null)
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else if (mErrDesc != null) 
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mErrDesc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else 
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Unknown error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}.execute();
```

Comment: My Android platform is 4.2

Comment: So you will get the exception. I'll update my answer with sample solution of how to avoid this

Comment: @user1767718 which exception do you get?

Comment: what do you get in stacktrace?
you can also modify the line `mErrDesc = "Exception thrown";` to `mErrDesc = "Exception thrown: " + ex.getMessage();` to get the exception in your toast

Comment: You need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Yes. I forget that.. oh god...I'm so careless!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it depends for what Android platform are you building. Not is the same build for 2.3 or 4.0. If you are building for 2.2 or less than 3.0 use HttpClient. [here](http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/) an example.